# zf3 change locale depending on user selection

Tags: php, zend-framework, translation, setlocale, zf3

I have Zend Framework 3 Application with working translator using po files.

I have configured it like this in my \config\global.php file:

```
'translator' => [
    'locale' => 'en_US',
    'translation_file_patterns' => [
        [
            'type'     => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => getcwd() .  '/data/language/',
            'pattern'  => '/%s/general.mo',
        ],
    ],
],
```

When i change the value of the "locale" it works ok and finds the proper .po file.
I need to be able to set the locale depending on a user profile's value saved in the database.

I have checked the documentation from here http://zendframework.github.io/zend-i18n/translation/ and the tutorial from here https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/i18n/ but they just mention the setLocale() method with no explanation or example. There is similar thread here [Zend framework 2 : How to set locale globaly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946906/zend-framework-2-how-to-set-locale-globaly) but it's for ZF2 and it doesn't provide working solution just some suggestions.

To summarize my question - how and where should i use the setLocale() method so it would be effective in the whole application and `$this->translate($message)` in all view files will use the new locale instead the default one used in the configuration file?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the PHP locale. To do so, use `\Locale::setDefault('en-GB');`.

Have a look at [SlmLocale](https://github.com/juriansluiman/SlmLocale/blob/7837559e31218a33b5c9b55d0e26e224befded90/Module.php#L97), this specific file is where it's done.

---

While that was the easiest way, you could also use the `setLocale` function on the MvcTranslator I guess. For that, you would need to override the existing factory with your own factory, therefore decorating the original one.

If you look at the [ConfigProvider file in zend-mvc-i18n](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc-i18n/blob/master/src/ConfigProvider.php#L35), you can see that aliases and factories are used here to create the MVC translator. Then you can see how the factory in question works, it basically creates a decorate translator, as [stated in the doc](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc-i18n/blob/master/doc/book/services.md#mvctranslator-and-translatorfactory).

By default, the service manager always provide the same instance (shared service), just like a singleton.

What we will therefore do is override this configuration (ie. make sure your own module is after the `Zend\Mvc\I18n` in `modules.config.php`). Then, in the module configuration, we can provide our own translator.

Our translator basically consist of the translator from the documentation, on which the `setLocale` is called. In order to do so, we can use a [delegator](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-servicemanager/delegators/).

```
return [
    'factories' => [
        TranslatorInterface::class => TranslatorServiceFactory::class,
    ],
    'delegators' => [
        TranslatorInterface::class => [
            \Application\Factory\TranslatorFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
];
```

And then the `TranslatorFactory`:

```
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\DelegatorFactoryInterface;

class TranslatorFactory implements DelegatorFactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $name, callable $callback, array $options = null)
    {
        $translator = call_user_func($callback);
        $translator->setLocale('en-GB');
        return $translator;
    }
}
```

That would be one way to do it (you get the container in that factory, so you could get some user data probably).

---

Another solution is to use the event system, and only declare the locale in the event listener where you retrieve your user details.

Comment: Thank you Thomas, this really works, I will try with the factory too, yet I will  appreciate some help with it. I think it will be more consistent to use framework's tools when there are such. I'll give a chance for someone else to suggest something else and if nobody hops in, I'll mark your answer  as "accepted". Thank you once again,

Comment: I just updated the answer a bit... That's a tad long IMO, and probably a bit confusing at some point, please ask more details if needed.

Comment: Thank you once again. I think i get the idea - we are "wrapping" the translator service with this delegator, which should be called (and will set locale) each time when `$this->translate($msg)` is called ? Unfortunately i can't make it work, I have added the configuration to the module.config.php of the Application module, and i have created the TranslatorFactory class in /Application/src/Factory/TranslatorFactory.php file is this all ?